# Display data from database special characters

Tags: php, mysql, database, special-characters

Database with UTF-8 encoded with some data in it and when I fetch, it displays me special characters. But at the same time my page have arabic text  written is displaying in a correct way.

Only the problem is when I fetch the data from database it is showing special characters.

Database and tables columns are utf8-general-ci encoded.

Answer (score 0):

You should change to utf8-bin.

Comment: Thanks but now it cannot be possible. Only what should we change in our php code to show the original content